# SQL update, compare and foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql-update, foreign-keys, compare, inner-join

I added a foreign key `id_customer` into my table `comment`.
But now I need to synchronize this foreign key `id_customer` with the primary key into `customer` table.

For that I compare emails into `customer` and `comment`.

```
UPDATE comment
    SET comment.id_customer = customer.id
    FROM comment, customer
    WHERE comment.email = customer.login
```

Apparently I have a syntax mistake. Someone can tell me why I'm wrong ? 
I also tried with INNER JOIN but same result.

Thanks. Sry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try an update with join :

```
UPDATE comment 
JOIN customer ON comment.email = customer.login
SET comment.id_customer = customer.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want `update` with a `join`:

```
UPDATE comment co JOIN
       customer cu
       ON co.email = cu.login
    SET co.id_customer = cu.id ;
```

This is MySQL-specific syntax.  The code in your question appears to be using SQL Server conventions.